# linux + increase temporary the /tmp partition for installation

Tags: linux, partition

I have linux VM machines with version red-hat 4

I have the following file system

```
df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             950M  163M  739M  19% /
/dev/sda1             130M   13M  118M  10% /boot
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda6              96M   18M  899M   2% /tmp
/dev/sda3             2.8G  1.2G  1.5G  44% /usr
/dev/sda5               5G  152M  765M  17% /var
```

I need to install some oracle KIT that need **/tmp** at least **2G** , while my free **/tmp** is **96M**

Can someone advice what my alternative?  In order to install my oracle KIT

Not sure but I was thinking about to create link from /tmp to /usr but I guess I will stay with the same problem , or maybe some other creative solution ?

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

899M available of 96M size /tmp doesn't make sense, nor does 765M available of 5G /var.  Is your table correct?

None of your file systems say 2G free. Free up space or make bigger partitions.

If some of /var frees up, a symlink from /var/tmp to /tmp  may work.  Perhaps some deleted files are still open, reboot.